# Next.js Ecommerce Template

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm fairly new at web development. I want to customize Next.js ecommerce template, but I sincerly don't know how to start. Needless to say, I'm new at programming, so I'm just asking for a summary of the steps I have to follow in order to do that. I'm runnning an ecommerce project and it catch my attention that template. Just need the Navbar, Authentication section and the cart.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRVZG.png)I've clonee the repository and do the simple stuff like getting the dependencies but aside that, don't know how to continue or what should I do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like the Next.js starter for Medusa: https://medusajs.com/nextjs-commerce/

It is fully open source and will give you both the backend (order, customer, product handling) and frontend setup (product grid, cart etc.) out of the box.